# Is there a PHP function that will return the block ID generated by WordPress?

Tags: php, functions, block-editor

I've tried the `parse_blocks()` function, however it returns all of the blocks. I'm needing to narrow it down to just the current block's ID. Is there a PHP function for that?

I'm needing get the unique ID for the block so I can set a transient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on your parsed blocks to get the right block.

```
$blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
foreach ( $blocks as $key => $block ) {
    if ( 'block_xxxxx' === $block[ 'id' ] ) {
        // do some action here
    }
}
```

Comment: The block type/name gets used several times on the page, so that would only narrow it down to a collection of those blocks for me. I'm trying to obtain the ID so I can refer to the block directly.

Comment: How do you know which block you want to target if you have it multiple times on your page?

Comment: I need each block to be able access its own unique ID in the PHP. I see that WP generates one, but I'm not sure if there is way to get that on the frontend. I might have to generate it with ```uniqid()``` , however that presents its own set of issues.

Comment: I still don't understand how you will know which ID is the one you want to target as they are dynamically generated. What do you want to do with the targeted block?

Comment: I think the point here is that this method doesn't exist. I was looking for something similar to the ```get_the_ID()``` function, however it appears this generated ID changes each time the block is saved. Which makes this approach pointless. Closing down the question.

Comment: Indeed, this will change without letting you know. If you render your blocks server side, you can always use the block name to add some class to your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this, so you pick up innerBlocks:

```
<?php
function parseBlocks($blocks, $block_id)
{
  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    if($block['blockName'] == $block_id) {
      return $block['attrs']['data'];
    }
    if (!empty($block['innerBlocks'])) {
      if ($data = parseBlocks($block['innerBlocks'], $block_id)) {
        return $data;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function getBlockFromPage($post_id, $block_id)
{
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if (!$post) return false;
  return parseBlocks(
    parse_blocks($post->post_content),
    $block_id
  );
}

// Just use like this:
$block_data = getBlockFromPage($post->ID, 'acf/test_name');
```